# In prediction modelling, is it bad practice to combine differing sampling frequencies of covariates into the same model?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, unevenly-spaced-time-series, midas

An example of this type of prediction task is modelling economic time-series data.  Depending on the type of data being reported, the sampling frequency varies: GDP is reported quarterly, employment reports monthly, money supply weekly, and interest rates daily.

If I want to predict some quantity, say inflation 5 days into the future, using quarterly GDP, monthly employment data, weekly money supply, and daily interest rates as my inputs. When using multiple regression, would it make sense to have monthly and quarterly data as covariates? My main concern is that looking at my design matrix, there are lots of repeating consecutive values corresponding to lower frequency data, which looks odd but I'm not sure if they present an issue.

I had a thought of disaggregating the lower-frequency data, such as using splines to interpolate between data points. This would work well for analysing relationships, but in forecasting I understand this method to be less robust because I cannot interpolate between now and a future point that has not yet been observed. Interpolation, as I understand it, is basically a univariate forecast which assumes a local trend, and in cases where this does not hold, I wonder if there are better approaches.

I'd like to understand which approach is appropriate -- whether to simply lump low frequency data along with high frequency data into a single regression model, or to attempt to somehow disaggregate the data so that they're all the same sampling frequency. I'd also be open to learn about alternate approaches, as I'm relatively new to the subject.

Comment: Check out the `midas` tag and the concept behind it.